# event parameter on loadhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I'm loading multiple files with an input and I have this:

```
function getAsText(fileToRead, index) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = loadHandler;
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
}
```

In fileToRead there is the file[x]

My load handler look this way:

```
function loadHandler(event) {
var csv = event.target.result;
processData(csv);
}
```

And this works for one file. The problem is that I want to add an 'index' parameter to the loadHandler to know which file I'm reading. So I tried this:

```
reader.onload = loadHandler(this.event, index);
```

but this.event isn't working and loadHandler receives and empty event so it fails in 'event.target.result'

What should be the event?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure callback like

```
function getAsText(fileToRead, index) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        loadHandler(event, index)
    };
    reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
}

function loadHandler(event, index) {
    var csv = event.target.result;
    processData(csv);
}
```